# How can I detect whether a UIWebView is zooming?

Tags: uiwebview, zooming

every one:

I can enable zooming by setting scalesPageToFit to YES.
But, how can I know whether UIWebView is zooming?

Does anyone know that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but could you do something with the Pinch Gesture Recogniser in relation to the UIWebView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved.

add a new property to XXXViewController to store current zoom scale (compared to initial scale)

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) float zoomScale;
```

set initial value of zoomScale at some proper place (e.g. viewDidLoad?)

```
self.zoomScale = 1.0f;
```

update zoom scale when the scale of ScrollView is changed (the ScrollView of UIWebView)

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale{
    self.zoomScale *= scale;
}
```

if zoomScale is within certain range (almost 1.0), the WebView is not zooming

```
if(self.zoomScale - 1.0 < 0.001 && self.zoomScale - 1.0 > - 0.001) {
    // Not zooming
}
```

And, if you want to change the scale, you should

```
- (void)changeWebViewScale:(float)scale
{
    [self.webView.scrollView setZoomScale:scale / self.zoomScale animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.seeques.com/19639347/how-to-detect-zoom-scale-of-uiwebview.html

In my case I had to add a `scrolview` var and `scrolviewdelegate`,then set that `scrolview` to `webview's` `scrolview` to be able to call `scrolviewdidendzooming` method